# Show full path to DLL in VS call stack window

Tags: c++, debugging

when my application crashes, I see in call stack window that crash occured in opencv_core220.dll
You may see the screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k9qgrk0ongq0giy/callstack.PNG).

But I would like to see the full path to this dll. Is there a way?
The fact is that I've got several such dlls on my PC and moreover,
some of them have the same name but are actually different.

And please, do not point me to the articles that explain "dll searching order in Windows" :)

I just want to know the full path right within the call stack window.

Thanks in advance,
Anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the modules tab in debugging, there you'll get a list of all loaded binaries and their full path: `Debug -> Windows -> Modules`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I've needed.

Answer (score 0):

MS VC has a tool called dependency, try it.
:)
good luck

Comment: Nope, it's called "Dependency Walker".